# "As in" in japanese

Tags: syntax, phrases

Just a quick question here, but somehow hard to find:
How could I say "as in" in japanese ?

For example :

> I learned the kanji 「評」as in 「評論」today.

Here is my attempt, sorry for the lousy japanase :

> 今日、評論のように評の漢字を覚えました。

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply use の:

> - 今日は「評論」の「評」の漢字を覚えました。
> - ブラボーのB、デルタのD
> - 「服を着る」の「着る」じゃなくて、「髪の毛を切る」[方](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42485/5010)の「切る」です。

Comment: Doesn't 「髪の毛を切る」方 need a の before 方?

Comment: @Sweeper I think it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely say:

私は「評判」の評、「評価」の評、「評論」* の評のように、評の字を覚えました, or
私は「評判]、「評価、「評論」に用いられる（ように）、評の字を覚えました

as 評 is not exclusively used for the word, 評論.

Note: * in order of popularity.